# Build failed in AGP 8.0, Failed to apply plugin 'realm-android'. API 'android.registerTransform' is removed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Today i updated gradle plugin to 8.0, I am using realm for local database but after updating the plugin i am unable to build the project.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Work\rc_android_projects\synco\app\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'realm-android'.
   > API 'android.registerTransform' is removed.
     
     For more information, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-api.
     To determine what is calling android.registerTransform, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

i tried to use the kotlin sdk but result is same

Update : fixed it by updating realm plugin **10.14.1-transformer-api-SNAPSHOT**

Comment: please add comment if you found the solution

Comment: Hi Amer,
I fixed it by adding classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.14.1-transformer-api-SNAPSHOT"  in project level build.gradle

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update 21/04/2023 :**

This should be fixed with 10.15.1 which was just released.
update your realm classpath in build.gradle to be :

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.1"
```

[issue tracked here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7799#issuecomment-1505135195)

========================================================

After this update you **may** encounter another issues regarding your JDK:

> Cause: class io.realm.processor.Utils (in unnamed module @0x38d68d7c)
> cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol (in
> module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export
> com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x38d68d7c

solved by editing `org.gradle.jvmargs` property in `gradle.properties` :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs= ... --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
```

[second issue tracked here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7801)

Answer (score 6):

You should use:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.15.1"
```

when compiling with Android Gradle Plugin 8.0 or newer

Comment: 10.15.0 was released too quickly and turned out to not work after all. 10.15.1 is now available on Maven Central and contains a rewrite of the problematic APIs and should thus work correctly with Java 17.

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7799#issuecomment-1516818238

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.17.0"
```