Android Studio erro: "Android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin."
I'm updating an old android project to build and run in the newest version of gradle, but I'm stuck in this error, and I don't know how to get over it.
The error when building my android studio project:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
My gradle project:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.egpv.ponton"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:30.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
//    implementation 'gr.escsoft.michaelprimez.searchablespinner:SearchableSpinner:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
}

I could'nt find any related problem in the stackoverflow that worked for my case.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47268938/150978

There is not a duplicate because the solution from this post is to remove apt-android, and in my project i dont have apt-android

My guess is that realm-android indirectly references apt-android and thus causes problems. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/76026649/150978
